# Prefetch_related many to many

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I need your help.
I have two models with manytomany relationship, I'm using prefetch_related but I'm having some problems trying to render the QuerySet in the template.

My question is, how can I show the data in the html file.

The models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'stores'
```

The view:

```
def mtmtest(request):
    books = Book.objects.prefetch_related('stores').all()
    return render(request, 'mtm.html', {'books': books})
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? At first look it seems the it should be `Book.objects.prefetch_related('stores_set').all()`

Comment: And then in the template, just iterate through books: `{% for book in books %} {{ book.name }} {% endfor %}`